# Cartthrob notifications for cancelled orders

Tags: cartthrob

In Cartthrob I notice a number of orders that have not been completed, looking under the payment error field I see "Transaction in process offsite" which means they cancelled their order while using the payment gateway. Is it possible to send an email when this error occurs with the customers details? I tried setting up notifications using the event "Customer completing order offsite" but that does not work. Any suggestions? Also is it possible to send to an email listed in the custom field e.g.{shipping_region}

Answer (score 1):

(I'm with Vector; we make CartThrob)

You may want to consider the [Abandoned Cart Notifications add-on](https://www.cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/expired-cart-notifications). Depending on your requirements and who should be emailed, it may help.

Otherwise, you could setup a cron job to query these, and if it's been long enough, email you the details. The reason is that CartThrob doesn't "know" if someone truly abandoned the checkout or are still there, filling in their information. We can help you with that if you'd like; get in touch via support@cartthrob.com!